# Is there any way to iterate over future<list> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-get

I would like to iterate over the the `Future<list>` but get errors if I try using for loops or if I try setting it as `List`.

Is there any other way of looping over each element in the list:

```
Future<List> getDailyTask(DateTime date) async {
  var params = {'date': date.toIso8601String()};
  Uri uri = Uri.parse('URL');
  final newURI = uri.replace(queryParameters: params);
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    newURI,
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
  );

  List foo = json.decode(response.body);
  return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't iterate directly on future but you can wait for the future to complete and then iterate on the List.

You can use either of these methods, depending upon your use-case.

```dart
List dailyTaskList = await getDailyTask(DateTime.now());
// Now you can iterate on this list.
for (var task in dailyTaskList) {
  // do something
}
```

or

```dart
getDailyTask(DateTime.now()).then((dailyTaskList) {
  for (var task in dailyTaskList) {
    // do something
  }
});
```